# all gtk applications opened with warning "assertion `gdk_error_traps != NULL' failed"

Tags: gtk

When opening any gtk application in the gnome-terminal I see the same warning

> Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_error_trap_pop: assertion `gdk_error_traps != NULL' failed

Don't know how it comes. Anyone knows how/where to fix it? I'm appreciative of knowing whether it's a bug and where the bug report could be found. This thing kept showing up since I upgraded to 12.10 from 12.04. And I'm surprisingly impressed as if I'm the only one bothered by this.

Comment: Do the applications still run, though?

Comment: At first glance it looks like this is a bug in the `10_no_nonnative_crash` patch in the Ubuntu packaging for libcanberra, but I can't find a bug report for it.

Comment: Yes, the applications run with no problem. This issue was there since I upgraded to 12.10. I cannot find any similar bug report either. At first I thought it's some inconsistency due to glib schema changes in the new version and it will flush out during update. However it does not.

Answer (score 3):

You are referencing to this bug in launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/1075928